# Simple Cronjob to backup a directory

Tags: zip, cron

I know this seems pretty trivial but I can't see to get this to work in cronjob.

I am running

```
zip -r /backup/$(date +'%Y%m%d').zip /var/www
```

This works fine. It gives me zip file in my backup directory.

But I will open Cron tab with

```
crontab -e
```

And I append this to the bottom of the file so it does daily updates.

This is where it doesn't work.

What am I doing wrong?

Edit: crontab looks like

```
0 1 * * * /home/serveradmin/backup.sh
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In cron the `%` (percent) sign needs to be escaped. You should comment out the percent signs with a `\` (backslash) in front of them. i.e.,

> date +\%Y-\%m-\%d-\%H-\%M